# Хранение в массиве ссылок на другой массив

Tags: java, коллекции

Как можно хранить в одном массиве (1)ссылки на другой массив(2). Производя изменения во втором массиве менялись значения в первом.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно понять, чем отличаются изменяемые объекты от неизменяемых. Скорее всего, вы эспеременировали с неизменяемыми объектами.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    class MyObj {
        private int someField;

        public MyObj(int someField) {
            this.someField = someField;
        }

        public void setSomeField(int someField) {
            this.someField = someField;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "MyObj{" +
                    "someField=" + someField +
                    '}';
        }
    }


    MyObj obj1 = new MyObj(1);
    MyObj obj2 = new MyObj(2);
    MyObj [] firstArray = {obj1, obj2};
    MyObj [] secondArray = {obj1, obj2};

    System.out.println("Before: ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(firstArray));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(secondArray));

    firstArray[0].setSomeField(111);
    firstArray[1].setSomeField(222);

    System.out.println("After: ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(firstArray));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(secondArray));
}
```

Результат:

```
Before: 
[MyObj{someField=1}, MyObj{someField=2}]
[MyObj{someField=1}, MyObj{someField=2}]
After: 
[MyObj{someField=111}, MyObj{someField=222}]
[MyObj{someField=111}, MyObj{someField=222}]
```